# How to handle errors in a Spring-MVC project without if else?

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, exception

I can’t understand how to handle the following error:

In the class `CustomerService` I delete the customer by `id`, and if such an `id` does not exist, then an error must be thrown! How can you do without an `if` `else`  construct?

`CustomerService`:

```java
// Delete customer
    public void deleteCustomer(Long id){
            Customer customer = customerRepository.getByIdAndUserRole(id, "customer");
            customerRepository.delete(customer);
        }
```

`CustomerController`:

```java
// DELETE MAPPING
    //
    // Delete customer with ID
    @DeleteMapping("/customers/{id}")
    void deleteCustomer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        customerService.deleteCustomer(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use Controller Advice. Whenever a exception occur it will directly handled by the handler. No if/else or try/catch blocks will be required.

1) Create a class CustomerControllerHandler, annotate with @ControllerAdvice.

2) Now create methods with arguments having the type of Exception.

3) The methods will return the JSON/POJO/void you want.

4) Annotate the methods with @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class) and 
      @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST),

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class CustomerControllerHandler {
     @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
     @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
     public void processException(Exception ex) {
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#deleteById-ID-) instead. It's the `deleteById` method for a `CrudRepository` (hope you're using that) and it throws `IllegalArgumentException` if it can't find a customer.

I assumed that with "error" you meant "exception" and then in the controller you can surround with a try-catch block like that:

```
try{
    customerService.deleteCustomer(id);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    log.error("No customer id exists!", e); 
    // if you have no logger, then use System.out.println() at least
}
```

If you wanted instead to return an error to the caller, then change the data type from void to `HttpResponse<String>` and when catching an exception you can `return HttpResponse<>("No customer exists with that id!", HTTP.BAD_REQUEST)`. Now the caller will get a 400 - bad request.

A nicer approach would be to catch the exception in the service itself and return a boolean to the controller (`true` if customer is deleted and `false` if couldn't delete / couldn't find one).

Comment: That's a bad approach. It's worth checking id is not null to avoid IllegalArgumentException, so try-catch block is not recommended here.

Comment: That's what @NotNull is used for in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to throw error then you will have to check a condition, that is there will be an if statement, but not necessarily an else is needed.

For instance, you can check response of delete and throw error according to below one.

```
if (deleteCount == 0) {
  //throw error here
}
```